# How to update multiple columns using PreparedStatement in Java - JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to update multiple columns data in my MySQL database with Java application through using PreparedStatement but I could not figure out how to do it.

**Here is the code query for  updating:**

```
String s = "UPDATE items SET name =" + u.getName() + ",category="
                + u.getCategory() + ", price=" + u.getPrice()
                + "   ,qunatity=" + u.getQuantity() + " WHERE id = '"
                + u.getId() + "'; ";
```

Comment: "i am facing some problem" What is the exact error you get?

Answer (score 64):

**No, no, no and no!**

Do **NOT** build SQL statements by concatenating strings. I thought we had been over this a long time ago. It is a *very* bad practice and a *very* good way to create errors and let *huge* security holes into your applications. Creating SQL statements by concatenating strings is a recipe for disaster and a bad habit that needs to be killed off before it takes hold.

[Use prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) - it will save you a lot of pain in the long run.

For example, compare what you have written with this:

```
PreparedStatement update = connection.prepareStatement
    ("UPDATE items SET name = ?, category = ?, price = ?, quantity = ? WHERE id = ?");

update.setString(1, u.getName());
update.setString(2, u.getCategory());
...
update.setInt(5, u.getId());

update.executeUpdate();
```

Sure, it is slightly more verbose, but far more readable and far less error-prone - not to mention that JDBC takes care of those pesky quoting issues that make [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) possible.

Comment: Should this approach be used for `Insert` also?

Comment: @GAMA: it should be used for any SQL statement with a variable part. Insertion, deletion, updates, dropping tables etc. are all good candidates.

Comment: I agree with the solution, but the criticism is not constructive in assuming every developer understands the implications of their code; This should be edited without such bias.

Comment: Very good answer, thank you. It made my code cleaner and made me hate SQL query little less :)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing quotes around the string values.

```
SET name = '" + u.getName() + "', ...
           ^                   ^
```

Also you have a typo. `qunatity` should probably be `quantity`.

I would also suggest that you look at parameterized queries. Your current code has a risk of SQL injection.

Comment: please make me the entire query

Comment: @user1525293 +1 for hilarious degree of honesty.